# Is there a style guide for SICP exercises?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I'm currently working my way through SICP, but I'm not quite used to the style of writing Scheme code yet. Is there any sort of style guide that is a companion for the book? So far, I have only found the comments on "pretty-printing" that are found [in section 1.1.1](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%25_sec_1.1.1).

Comment: FYI, http://community.schemewiki.org/?SICP-Solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gerald Jay Sussman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Jay_Sussman), one of the authors of [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html), is also one of the authors of Scheme. Their really cool [1986 video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE18841CABEA24090) at HP they don't expect Scheme to be that well known so they call it the more general name Lisp. Don't get confused since SICP is 100% Scheme and thus scheme coding style would be the correct path.

The Scheme wiki has a [style guide](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-style) together with common [variable naming conventions](http://community.schemewiki.org/?variable-naming-convention) and [comment style](http://community.schemewiki.org/?comment-style).

Scheme was a new dialect of Lisp with lexical closures and one namespace as core features. It uses `define` instead of `defun`, `defparameter`, and `defvar`. DrRacket IDE actually treats lists with the operator starting with "de" as `define`. eg.

```
;;; example procedure test
(define (test arg1 arg2)
  ;; two space indent after define, let and friends
  (if (test? arg1 arg2)                   ; predicates tend to end with ?
      (consequent arg1 arg2)              ; if you split if then arguments align
      (alternative "extra long argument"  ; if you split arguments in procedure call arguments are aligned
                   arg1
                   arg2)))                ; ending parens keep together
```

In Common Lisp most of the coding style is the same:

```
;;; example function test
(defun test (arg1 arg2)
  ;; two space indent after defun, let and friends
  (if (testp arg1 arg2)                   ; predicates tend to end with p
      (consequent arg1 arg2)              ; if you split if then arguments align
      (alternative "extra long argument"  ; if you split arguments in procedure call arguments are aligned
                   arg1
                   arg2)))                ; ending parens keep together
```

The standard reference for Common Lisp style, including commenting conventions, is Peter Norvig and Kent Pitman's [Tutorial on Good Lisp Programming Style](http://www.norvig.com/luv-slides.pdf). This you can use as a supplement for the Scheme resources.

PS: Coding style is opinionated. The language don't care much for any of this so this is just to make the code easier to read for humans.

Comment: Is there a typo in the string? "extra **ling** argument". Is there a typo in the comments? "alignt".

Comment: @Flux yeah. Corrected it to `"extra long argument"`` :-)

Comment: What's "alignt"?